# Do we need to consider encoding (UTF-8) while constructing a string from char* buffer

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am working on a HTTP Client module which receives information from server in a character buffer and is UTF-8 encoded. I wanted to create a std::string object from this character buffer.

Can I create a string object directly by passing the character buffer like this ?

```
 std::string receivedstring(receievedbuffer,bufferlength);
```

here receievedbuffer is char[] array which contains data received from TCP/IP connection and bufferlength contains the number of bytes received. I am really confused with the term UTF-8 , I understood that its a unicode encoding , do I need to take any steps before the conversion.

Comment: At some point -when the string is completed- you should validate the UTF-8 string (e.g. with [u8_check](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/Elementary-string-checks.html#Elementary-string-checks) etc...), since it is from the Internet and not every byte string is valid UTF-8. Read [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) wikipage. Once you have validated it, having it in a `std::string` -for future output- is ok.

Comment: Well, what are you going to do with the string next? How do you want to store this text? Which encoding do you wish to use internally?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : It means I need to go through the character buffer initially to check whether it contains valid UTF-8 , then I can continue with normal string operations without worrying about encoding right?

Comment: Yes. normal string operations work on validated UTF-8. Then you can continue if you have decided that every Unicode string is represented in UTF-8 (but not e.g. UTF-16). But you need to read more about UTF-8.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I will be passing extracted HTTP headers internally. UTF-8 encoding will work as far as I understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::string receivedstring(receievedbuffer,bufferlength);
```

It does not do any conversion, it just copies from `receievedbuffer` to `receivedstring`.

If your `receievedbuffer` was UTF-8 encoded then the the exact same bytes will be stored into `receivedstring`.

std::string is just a storage format and does not reflect the encoding of the data stored in it.